# Selenium Click and Page Load issue in AWS fargate with 24 chrome nodes and 2048 CPU and 1024 memory

Tags: performance, selenium-webdriver, grid, click, loading

AWS fargate with multiple Chrome nodes. Below is our settings in

```
- **fargate.tf**

Chrome Browsers = 24 Threads **12 Nodes with 2 session each **
Memory = 2048 
CPU = 1024 

Chrome Version = 120
Selenium Grid = 4.16.1`

- **tasks.tf**

SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS = "2"
```

We are trying to run 38 test case via PYTEST Framework and out the 38 only 12 are passing and remaining test fails with different reasons as mentioned below:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: 

Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Can someone throw some light on this, its bothering us for last few days and not able to find a solution.

We tried to fix at the code level by using different types of clicks and to control page loading issues we increased timeouts unto 3 mins which is impacting the overall build duration but still we see same type of failures.

When number of parallel threads was reduce we are seeing less failures on both click and page loading issue. Please see below.

```
24 threads : 66 Failures out of 169 test cases
12 threads : 7 Failures out of 169 test cases
```